# Click and drag one pixel in given direction

Tags: autohotkey

I am looking for a script that will click and hold the right mouse button down and drag in a given direction 1 pixel every "x" or 2 seconds. Something I can either tell to move in given direction by hitting the corresponding direction key or by adjusting the script manually.

Thank you!

Comment: Trying to do this myself but right mouse button down part is still a little messed up. It moves the cursor about 3 times to the right without holding down the right mouse button, and then it starts to kick in and constantly holds down the right mouse button. Not sure why it's not getting the first 3 or so screenshots with the right mouse button down.

`code #Persistent

$F10::Capture()
Numpad0::ExitApp

Capture()
{
    hours := 1.0
    Loop, % hours*720
    {
  Click Down Right
        MouseMove, 1, 0, 0, R
        Send, {PrintScreen}
  Sleep, 2000
    }
}
`

Comment: It seems to work fine to move the mouse to the right or down, but as soon as I enter a negative integer such as -1, it moves the mouse about 3 times , like before, and then right clicks, but the screen does not move after that as if the mouse stops moving once the right click has been held down.

Comment: maybe you should put the code in your question

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you want, but try this:

```
CoordMode, Pixel, Screen

direction = left
secondsBetweenMoves = 0.1

F1:: ;F1 to start it
    SendInput, {LButton Down}
    SetTimer, Move, %secondsBetweenMoves%
Return
F2:: ;F2 to end it
    SendInput, {LButton Up}
    SetTimer, Move, Off
Return

Move:
    MouseGetPos, mouseX, mouseY
    If (direction = "left") {
        MouseMove, mouseX-1, mouseY
    }
    Else If (direction = "right") {
        MouseMove, mouseX+1, mouseY
    }
    Else If (direction = "up") {
        MouseMove, mouseX, mouseY-1
    }
    Else If (direction = "down") {
        MouseMove, mouseX, mouseY+1
    }
Return
```

Answer (score 0):

The send event command might make your life a whole lot easier. For example, what you're trying to do in a simplistic infinite loop:

```
coordmode, mouse, screen
setmousedelay, 0        # This makes the mouse move extremely fast

loop {
    mousegetpos, mx, my
    mx := mx+1
    sendevent {click, r, down}
    sendevent {click, %mx%, %my%, r, up}
    sleep 2000
}
```

This loop will hold down the right button and move one pixel to the right every two seconds. If you want it to move to the left, change

```
mx := mx+1
```

to

```
mx := mx-1
```

Making it move up or down is the same mechanism, but adding or subtracting to the variable "my" instead.

This loop can be made into a timer, with hotkeys to enable or disable it.